# Android Applying style from resources to a Paint object

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-styles

In my application, I am drawing text on a Canvas.

To do so, I am using the drawText method on Canvas:

`void   drawText(String text, float x, float y, Paint paint)`

I would like to set the style of the text to match a style defined in my styles.xml file:

`<style name="ZI_DetailText">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:capitalize">characters</item>
        <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>/>
</style>`

Is there a way to do this by directly referencing the style in code (on the Paint object, maybe? ), or do I need to reconstruct it using setTypeface, etc ?

Comment: Does the `canvas` belong to a Custom view, or are you just having the Canvas in the activity ?

Comment: It is in a custom view, more particularly, in an ItemTouchHelper.Callback, which is called when an item in my recyclerview is swiped.

Comment: I think that is not possible if you draw text on canvas but you can declare styleable in attr.xml. Use TypedArray in your custom view to declare style.